# How to fix zoom in and zoom out in three js?

Tags: three.js

I am using three js for loading 3D model on webpage.and i used PerspectiveCamera class to see 3d model.but when i zoom out that 3d model it dispppears.how to fix that issue?

This is my code in javascript

```
import { GLTFLoader } from './GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './OrbitControls.js';


var scene, camera, renderer, obj, newMaterial;
var object_name = [];       //array to store object_name getting from api.
var exhibitor_id = localStorage.getItem('exhibitor');
console.log(exhibitor_id)
function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //camera

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    // camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 700);

    // renderer

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    $('.model').append(renderer.domElement)

    var loader = new GLTFLoader();
    //filepath:it is path for scene.gltf file
    loader.load(filepath, function (gltf) {

        obj = gltf.scene;
        obj.position.set(0, -200, 0);
        obj.traverse(function (object) { object.frustumCulled = false; });
        scene.add(obj);
        animate();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/3dbasetextures/1',
            data: {},
            success: function (response) {
                for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    object_name.push(response[i].object_name)
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
            },
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/3dcollage/' + exhibitor_id,
            data: {},
            success: function (response) {
                // console.log("3dtextures", data.data[0].collage_path);
                var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                console.log(response.data)
                for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    // console.log(i, response.data[i])
                    if (response.data[i].collage_path != null) {
                        var newTexture = textureLoader.load(response.data[i].collage_path);
                        var posterobj = obj.getObjectByName(object_name[i]);
                        posterobj.material.map = newTexture;
                        newTexture.flipY = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Images not creted.")
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });


        console.log(object_name)
    });



    // background
    // scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xC1C1C1);

    // light
    // var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x000000, 3);
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x000000, 3);
    scene.add(light);


    //controls 
    controller();

    scene.add(camera);
}

function controller() {

    var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.target.set(0, 1, 0);

    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controls.minAzimuthAngle = -0.6;
    controls.maxAzimuthAngle = 1.5;
    controls.minPolarAngle = controls.maxPolarAngle = 1.57079
}


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    // controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// for implementing responsiveness
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
init();
```

There is one method to fix zoom in and out but it is applicable for OrthrographicCamera.
But PerspectiveCamera is more suitable for viewing 3D model

Answer (score 1):

For  Perspective Camera, zooming is called "dollying". you can use the distance (minDistance & maxDistance) to limit the zoom/ dolly.

```
controls.minDistance = <your value here>;
```

https://threejs.org/docs/?q=CONTROL#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls